# SQL count how many occur for specific value from table1 in table2

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have 2 tables, table1 name of selected food
table2 selected food for user in breakfast, lunch , dinner ,...

table 1:

```
id name
0 Apple
1 watermelon
2 Pear
3 Peach
4 Walnut
. .
200 Apricot
```

table 2:

```
id  username    breakfast  lunch  dinner  Meal1   Meal2  Meal3  
0   Dave        apple      null   Pear    null    null   watermelon
1   John        walnut     Peach  Pear    Apricot null   apple
.   ....        ......     .....  ....    ....... ....   .....
900 Ray         walnut     Peach  Pear    Apricot null   apple
```

note : user can't chose apple more than once in meals.

i want to find out how many for each foods chef want for this guests :

```
apple 400
Pear  399
Peach 398
```

i tried :

```
SELECT breakfast, COUNT( * ) AS value
FROM table2
WHERE breakfast !=  ""
GROUP BY breakfast
ORDER BY `value` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but it's not what i want,if users just want dinner the name of foods not appare in result.
Thanks.

Comment: homework should be attempted.

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry)
it can be done by just normalize the table2

```
SELECT name, value
FROM (    
SELECT breakfast AS name, COUNT( * ) AS value
FROM table2
WHERE breakfast !=  ""
GROUP BY breakfast
UNION 
SELECT lunch AS name, COUNT( * ) AS value
FROM table2
WHERE lunch !=  ""
GROUP BY lunch 
UNION 
SELECT dinner AS name, COUNT( * ) AS value
FROM table2
WHERE dinner !=  ""
GROUP BY dinner
UNION 
SELECT meal1 AS name, COUNT( * ) AS value
FROM table2
WHERE meal1 !=  ""
GROUP BY meal1
UNION 
SELECT candid5 AS name, COUNT( * ) AS value
FROM table2
WHERE meal2 !=  ""
GROUP BY meal2
UNION 
SELECT meal3 AS name, COUNT( * ) AS value
FROM table2
WHERE meal3 !=  ""
GROUP BY meal3
UNION 
SELECT meal4 AS name, COUNT( * ) AS value
FROM table2
WHERE meal4 !=  ""
GROUP BY meal4
) AS mynewtablename
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY  `mynewtablename`.`value` DESC
```

hope others learn from [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry)

and it help someone.